# skinning script works in fiddle but not live

Tags: jquery

Here is a link to a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cypx/12/), and here is the [live page](http://apecharmony.co.uk/Untitled-2.php) where it doesn't work.

Once you click "click", it should check to see if domain has a value and if not it dresses up a div as an error box. The "click" will become a button and there will be an input text box but as there is no domain the result should just be open dialog. Works in fiddle but not live code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<div onclick="check_domain_input()">Click</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Attention!" style="display:none">
    Please enter a domain name to search for.
</div>

<script>
    function check_domain_input()
    {        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); // Shows the new alert box.

        var domain_val = document.getElementsByName('domain');

        if (domain_val[0].value.length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you can't ask your question without depending on external links, it doesn't belong here. Your question needs to be answerable without me clicking either of those links.

Comment: @meagar Are you saying jsfiddle is not recommended? Not sure what the average SO user thinks of that..

Comment: @Ben Fiddles are fine, but they must not be the only content in your question. "Fix this fiddle" is *absolutely not* an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. Note that, before he fixed his question, it contained two links and the text "this fiddle works but my live site doesn't. Why?" The question has since been vastly improved.

Comment: it was lazy sry should give better discription and more in your face code to look at as it is clear here what is wrong and doesnt need the links. no one likes lazy!

Comment: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't come with jQueryUI by default.
Include it.

http://www.jqueryui.com

EDIT: Comments below imply confusion.

In your jsFiddle, underneath the jQuery library selection on the left-hand panel, you have ticked 'jquery ui'.
This is another javascript library, an extension of jQuery. You can download it at the above link.

It's got default UI-skinning, which is the CSS file you have already included.

You will also need to include the jQueryUI script BELOW / AFTER jQuery.

EDIT: Just add this line after `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: didnt i link it with <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

Comment: @DavidWalter. That's just the stylesheet. You also need the js library

Comment: @DavidWalter Also, use the power of the error console. It's pretty obvious you're missing something if you can the errors in the console..

Comment: isnt this the libary? <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> ---- was just testing the raw code before making my own css to dress the box, which would replace the jquery stylesheet.if that isnt the libary (<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>) then do i still need it if im using my own css?

Comment: [05:00:18.454] $("#dialog").dialog is not a function @ http://apecharmony.co.uk/Untitled-2.php:23.... is the error message

Comment: @DavidWalter - Better to start with jQueryUI CSS and tweak it as needed - there's a lot of things to style if you're starting from scratch.

Comment: but love css dont mindwriting it just need the framework to function

Comment: @DavidWalter jquery is a generic javascript library. _jquery ui_ is a separate library that uses jquery at its core. _jquery ui_ is composed of a javascript library _and_ a css style sheet called theme. You need all 3 things, jquery js, jquery ui js and jquery ui css.

Comment: and then just modify the the css as needed, and slowly delete features you dont require out of the ui but never touch the jquery?

Comment: Only @john-resig can touch the jquery

Comment: @DavidWalter: Please take a look as well here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/